# Swift Float to UInt8 conversion unnecessary?

Tags: swift

I have been getting a lot of errors about conversions in swift as of beta 4. I saw it was a pretty common problem and I was able to fix most of the errors except for this certain one:

```
let xDistance = testCircle.position.x - circle.position.x
let yDistance = testCircle.position.y - circle.position.y

let distance = (sqrt(pow(Float(xDistance), 2) + pow(Float(yDistance), 2)))
let minDist = testCircle.size.width * 1.5 + circle.size.width/2

if (distance >= minDist) {
    return true
}
```

the `if (distance >= minDist)` is returning the following error:

```
'Float' is not convertible to 'UInt8'
```

I'm not sure why I need to use UInt8 here, but I have tried fixing it and have just caused more conversion error. Anyone see the problem here?

Comment: Does it help if you replace the 2s in the above with 2.0? It might be inferring an integer type from that.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The problem still exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message doesn't make any sense, since the problem is that you're comparing a `Float` and a `CGFloat`. In previous Swift betas, CGFloat was (at least sometimes) aliased to Float, so you could get away with that, but in beta 4 it's its own type. You can just cast your float value to `CGFloat` in the comparison:

```
if (CGFloat(distance) >= minDist) {
    return true
}
```

It's safer to go `Float` -> `CGFloat` since on some architectures `CGFloat` is a `Double` under the hood.

Comment: Ah, seems that worked! Thanks for clearing that up for me. I guess in the end it is safer this way.